# SharedPreferences not working with int value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm writing an application for android and I have difficulties with saving int variable with SharedPreferences. I have checked my code thousand times and I haven't found the problematic part. I have two Activities. In Activity1 I have a button which leads to the second one. In Activity2 I have a button which is add 50 "points" to my variable. I save this variable in the onPause and onStop methods. After that I go back to Activity1 and I have 0 points again.

Activity1:

```
private static final String HINT = "Hint";
private static final String VALUE = "VALUE";
int hints;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainketto);      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainketto);

    SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    hints = sphint.getInt(VALUE, 0);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + hints,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Button points = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);


   points.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PointsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
 }


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {


         SharedPreferences sphint =     getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et2 = sphint.edit();
    et2.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et2.commit();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et2 = sphint.edit();
    et2.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et2.commit();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Activity2:

```
  private static final String HINT = "Hint";
  private static final String VALUE = "VALUE";
  int hints;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontpiac);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontpiac);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();


    SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    hints = sphint.getInt(VALUE, 0);


    Toast.makeText(Pontpiac.this, ""+hints,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tesztfos);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hints = hints + 50;
            Toast.makeText(Pontpiac.this, ""+hints,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {

    SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et2 = sphint.edit();
    et2.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et2.commit();

    super.onPause();
}

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
 SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et2 = sphint.edit();
    et2.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et2.commit();

    super.onStop();
}
```

If anyone has an idea how to make it work please response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the preference again in `onResume` of the first activity

Answer (score 1):

`Activity.onCreate()` is normally only called once, when the `Activity` is first created. It's like a virtual constructor. When you navigate back to Activity1 from Activity2, Activity1's `onCreate()` will not get called again. As @tyczj said in his answer, you need to override `onResume()` and get that value again. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    hints = sphint.getInt(VALUE, 0);
}
```

As an aside, I'm not sure why you're using `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(...)`. Your `Activity` is a `Context`. You can just call `getSharedPreferences(...)` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use my library: https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver is a "super" SharedPreference that allows you to save int, String and boolean like this:

```
KeySaver.saveShare(this, "your-key", 1); //or any int
```

To get the value:

```
KeySaver.getIntSavedShare(this, "your-key");
```